# Optimizing Mysql Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have two sql queries with different ways to get to the answer. I wanted to find the maximum number of time a column had same emp_no. Below are the EXPLAIN for each of the two queries.

query one:

[image]

SELECT MAX(counted) FROM {
SELECT count(emp_no) as counted
    FROM salaries GROUP BY emp_no
} as t

query two:

SELECT count(emp_no) as count
    FROM salaries GROUP BY emp_no
    ORDER BY count(emp_no) DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0

[image]

Table
+-----+------------+-------------+
| id  |  emp_no    |    salary   |
+-----+------------+-------------+
| 1   | 00001      | 10000       |
| 2   | 00002      | 20000       |
| 3   | 00003      | 10000       |
+-----+------------+-------------+

emp_no has index of type b tree with unique

Which one of the two would be better? Also, please suggest me some good reading materials to learn the optimisation techniques.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text, not everyone can see images [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Have you tested to see which query run faster? regarding optimization the most important is using proper index. Here is a nice material 
MySQL index [**TIPS**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: In MySQL, you may want to consider partitioning as well.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-overview.html

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza i ran the two queries they took almost identical times. But when I use explain query 1 is using 2 select_type PRIMARY and DERIVED of type all and index respectively with extra column NULL and INDEX; and query 2 is using using 1 SIMPLE select_type of type INDEX but in EXTRA it is using index, filesort, and using temp

Answer (score 0):

Your "query 2",

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Salaries
    GROUP BY emp_no
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

is shorter to write, and faster.

If `Salaries` has `INDEX(emp_no)`, the query can be performed inside the index's BTree.  Since the `EXPLAIN` says "Using index", this is the case.  It is called a "covering index".  This index is the best (and probably only) thing that can speed up the query.

`EXPLAIN` is less than perfect.

- Q#2 says "using temporary" and "using filesort".  But it is not as bad as it sounds.
- Q#1 shows two lines - but each indicates 2.8M rows.
- `LIMIT 1` has an impact that is not shown in either `EXPLAIN`.

Partitioning will not help.